# How to scrape all links in a page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a chrome extension to change all hrefs in a page using this code

```
var a = document.querySelector("a[href]");
a.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

But this code only fetches the first href but only if it is not embedded in another attribute(If the term is wrong I am meaning div, p, h etc.)

Could someone show me how to fetch all hrefs no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but only if it is not embedded in another attribute(If the term is wrong I am meaning div, p, h etc.)

I believe you are talking about tags instead of attributes. To select all tags with the present of the `href` attribute, do this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("*[href]");
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    list[i].href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) only returns the first element within the document, and so in this case you will want to use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which instead returns a list of all matching elements.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].href = 'http://google.com';
}
```